# Py4JError: SparkConf does not exist in the JVM

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running pyspark but it can be unstable at times. There are couple of times it crashes at this command

```
spark_conf = SparkConf()
```

with the following error message

```
     File "/home/user1/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/conf.py", line 106, in __init__
self._jconf = _jvm.SparkConf(loadDefaults)
     File "/home/user1/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 772, in __getattr__
raise Py4JError('{0} does not exist in the JVM'.format(name))
     Py4JError: SparkConf does not exist in the JVM
```

Any idea what is the problem? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

SparkConf does not exist in the pyspark context, try:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
```

in the pyspark console or code.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. After closing a SparkContext, I will get the above error message when I try to call SparkConf() and initialize a new SparkContext again.

Comment: What do you mean? I have the same error when using from pyspark import SparkContext and then sc = SparkContext()

Comment: @Michael how to closed spark session?

Comment: @JatinPatel-JP Use `spark.stop()` to stop a `SparkSession`. Here spark is the name of the `SparkSession` object.