# py4j.protocol.Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I am currently on JRE: 1.8.0_181, Python: 3.6.4, spark: 2.3.2

I am trying to execute following code in Python:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
```

This fails with following error:

> spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
>       sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
>     File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 349, in getOrCreate
>       SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
>     File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 118, in **init**
>       conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
>     File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 195, in _do_init
>       self._encryption_enabled = self._jvm.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled(self._jsc)
>     File "C:\Tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1487, in **getattr**
>       "{0}.{1} does not exist in the JVM".format(self._fqn, name))
>   **py4j.protocol.Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM**

Any one has any idea on what can be a potential issue here?

Appreciate any help or feedback here. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161939/pyspark-error-does-not-exist-in-the-jvm-error-when-initializing-sparkcontext

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54881624/1316649 It worked for me.

Answer (score 38):

Using findspark is expected to solve the problem:

**Install findspark**

`$pip install findspark`

**In you code use:**

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

Optionally you can specify "/path/to/spark" in the `init` method above; `findspark.init("/path/to/spark")`

Comment: Yes, you can `findspark.init()` before you import pyspark

Comment: `findspark.init()` must be called before importing `pyspark`.

Answer (score 30):

As outlined @ [pyspark error does not exist in the jvm error when initializing SparkContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161939/pyspark-error-does-not-exist-in-the-jvm-error-when-initializing-sparkcontext), adding `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (with value as:

`%SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-<version>-src.zip:%PYTHONPATH%`,
- just check what `py4j` version you have in your `spark/python/lib` folder) helped resolve this issue.

Comment: Are we for certain supposed to include a semicolon after `%SPARK_HOME%\python`?

Comment: I have followed the same step above, it worked for me. Just make sure that your spark version downloaded is the same as the one installed using pip command. Once this path was set, just restart your system.

Comment: I had to put the slashes in the other direction for it to work, but that did the trick.
eg. 
PYTHONPATH=/opt/spark/python;/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:%$

Comment: I can confirm that this solved the issue for me on WSL2 Ubuntu.

Comment: I first followed the same step above, and I still got the same error. The root cause for my case is that my local py4j version is different than the one in spark/python/lib folder. I try to pip install the same version as my local one, and check the step above, it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

**Solution #1. Check your environment variables**

You are getting “py4j.protocol.Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM” due to environemnt variable are not set right.

Check if you have your environment variables set right on .bashrc file. For Unix and Mac, the variable should be something like below. You can find the .bashrc file on your home path.

**Note**: Do not copy and paste the below line as your Spark version might be different from the one mentioned below.

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/python:$PATH
```

If you are running on windows, open the environment variables window, and add/update below.

```
SPARK_HOME  =>  /opt/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
PYTHONPATH  =>  %SPARK_HOME%/python;%SPARK_HOME%/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%
PATH  => %SPARK_HOME%/bin;%SPARK_HOME%/python;%PATH%
```

After setting the environment variables, restart your tool or command prompt.

**Solution #2. Using findspark**

Install findspark package by running $pip install findspark and add the following lines to your pyspark program

```
import findspark
findspark.init() 
# you can also pass spark home path to init() method like below
# findspark.init("/path/to/spark")
```

**Solution #3. Copying the pyspark and py4j modules to Anaconda lib**

Sometimes after changing/upgrading Spark version, you may get this error due to version incompatible between pyspark version and pyspark available at anaconda lib. In order to correct it

**Note**: copy the specified folder from inside the zip files and make sure you have environment variables set right as mentioned in the beginning.

Copy the **py4j** folder from :

```
C:\apps\opt\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\
```

to

```
C:\Programdata\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\.
```

And, copy **pyspark** folder from :

```
C:\apps\opt\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\
```

to

```
C:\Programdata\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\
```

Sometimes, you may need to **restart** your system in order to effect eh environment variables.

**Credits to** : https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-py4j-protocol-py4jerror-org-apache-spark-api-python-pythonutils-jvm/

Answer (score 10):

you just need to install an older version of pyspark .This version works"pip install pyspark==2.4.7"

Comment: This was helpful! PySpark version needed to match the Spark version.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, on Windows, and I found that my Python had different versions of **py4j** and **pyspark** than the spark expected.
Solved by copying the python modules inside the zips: **py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip** and **pyspark.zip** (found in **spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib**) into **C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages**.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case with spark 2.4.6, installing pyspark 2.4.6 or 2.4.x, the same version as spark, fixed the problem since pyspark 3.0.1(`pip install pyspark` will install latest version) raised the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced this issue.
mistake was - I was opening normal jupyter notebook.
Always open  **Anaconda Prompt -> type 'pyspark' -> It will automatically open Jupyter notebook** for you.
 After that, you will not get this error.

Answer (score 2):

if use pycharm 
 - Download spark 2.4.4
 - settings/project structure/addcontent root/ add    py4j.0.10.8.1.zip
   ve pyspark.zip in spark.2.4.4/python/lib

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if you have pip installed pyspark 3.1 and your local spark is 2.4 (I mean versions incompatibility)
In my case, to overcome this, I uninstalled spark 3.1 and switched to pip install pyspark 2.4.

My advice here is check for version incompatibility issues too along with other answers here.

Answer (score 2):

If not already clear from previous answers, your pyspark package version has to be the same as Apache Spark version installed.

For example I use Ubuntu and PySpark 3.2. In the environment variable (bashrc):

```
export SPARK_HOME="/home/ali/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2"
export PYTHON_PATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHON_PATH
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was using spark 3.2.1 so ```pip install pyspark==3.2.1``` solved similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### If you Updated pyspark or spark

If like me the problem occurred after you updated one of the two and you didn't know that Pyspark and Spark version need to match, as the Pyspark PyPi repo says:

> NOTE: If you are using this with a Spark standalone cluster you must **ensure** that the **version** (including minor version) **matches** or you may experience odd errors.

Therefor upgrading/downgrading Pyspark/Spark for their version to match solve the issue.

To **upgrade Spark** follow: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-py4j-protocol-py4jerror-org-apache-spark-api-python-pythonutils-jvm/

Answer (score 0):

If using Spark with the AWS Glue libs locally (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs), ensure that Spark, PySpark and the version of AWS Glue libs all align correctly.  As of now, the current valid combinations are:

| aws-glue-libs branch | Glue Version | Spark Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| glue-0.9 | 0.9 | 2.2.1 |
| glue-1.0 | 1.0 | 2.4.3 |
| glue-2.0 | 2.0 | 2.4.3 |
| master | 3.0 | 3.1.1 |

Answer (score 0):

Regarding previously mentioned solution with `findspark`, remember that it must be **at the top** of your script:

```
import sys
import findspark
findspark.init()
from...
import...
```