# pytest for creating sparksession on local machine

Tags: pyspark, pytest

I am trying to run a test for my pyspark code on windows local machine. Pytest is getting stuck at line where I am creating SparkSession in my test code. Do i have to install/configure spark on my local machine for Pytest to work. Finally the test will execute as part of CI/CD, do i have to configure Spark on build machines also? I have a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69198087/visual-studio-code-using-pytest-for-pyspark-getting-stuck-at-sparksession-creati), but looks like issue is not with Visual studio Code but pytest (as i have same issue when I run pytest from command line )

below is my test code

```
# test code

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row, DataFrame

import pytest

def test_poc():
   spark_session = SparkSession.builder.master('local[2]').getOrCreate()  #this line never returns when debugging test.
   spark_session.createDataFrame(data,schema) #data and schema not shown here.
```

Answer (score 0):

can you add the terminal output of your pyspark script? It will be helpful to understand where to begin with and it might give us a clue what it is the problem in your setup.

At least to see if you have installed `pyspark` correctly (you still might need to do additional operations to be fully sure), but you can do like below script saved in a python file `sample_test.py`

```
from pyspark import sql


spark = sql.SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("local-spark-session") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

And running it should print out something like below

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>python sample_test.py
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

C:\Users\user\Desktop>SUCCESS: The process with PID 16368 (child process of PID 12664) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 12664 (child process of PID 11736) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 11736 (child process of PID 6800) has been terminated.
```

And below is a sample test for pyspark using pytest saved in a file called `sample_test.py`

```
from pyspark import sql


spark = sql.SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("local-spark-session") \
        .getOrCreate()
        

def test_create_session():
    assert isinstance(spark, sql.SparkSession) == True
    assert spark.sparkContext.appName == 'local-spark-session'
    assert spark.version == '3.1.2'
```

Which you can simply run as below

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>pytest -v sample_test.py
============================================= test session starts =============================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\user\Desktop
collected 1 item

sample_test.py::test_create_session PASSED                                                               [100%]

============================================== 1 passed in 4.51s ==============================================

C:\Users\user\Desktop>SUCCESS: The process with PID 4752 (child process of PID 9780) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 9780 (child process of PID 8988) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 8988 (child process of PID 20176) has been terminated.
```

Above example is for windows. My account is new so I couldn't respond on your comments...**can you update your question to share the messages/errors from the terminal if there are any?** And by the way just wondering what OS are you using?

Comment: from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217767/py4j-protocol-py4jerror-org-apache-spark-api-python-pythonutils-getencryptionen. i checked my machine and saw there was some old installation of spark(sparkhome environment variable was present on machine) but the JavaHome was pointing to wrong directory. I removed all environment variables related to Spark/Python and it is working after that. So I assume spark installation is not required on local machine to create SparkSession. Just installing pyspark package is sufficient.