# Error when creating SparkSession in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I am trying to create a `SparkSession`, I get this error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getPythonAuthSocketTimeout does not exist in the JVM
```

This is my code:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Practice").getOrCreate()
```

What am I doing wrong. I am actually following a tutorial online and the commands are exactly the same. However the tutorial is doing it in Jupyter notebooks and I am doing it in VS Code.

Traceback:

```
22/09/01 08:50:02 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\BERNARD JOSHUA\OneDrive\Desktop\Swinburne Computer Science\PySpark\pySpark_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Practice").getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Users\BERNARD JOSHUA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 269, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Users\BERNARD JOSHUA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 483, in getOrCreate    
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Users\BERNARD JOSHUA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 197, in __init__       
    self._do_init(
  File "C:\Users\BERNARD JOSHUA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 302, in _do_init       
    self._jvm.PythonUtils.getPythonAuthSocketTimeout(self._jsc)
  File "C:\Users\BERNARD JOSHUA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1547, in __getattr__ 
    raise Py4JError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getPythonAuthSocketTimeout does not exist in the JVM
PS C:\Users\BERNARD JOSHUA\OneDrive\Desktop\Swinburne Computer Science\PySpark> SUCCESS: The process with PID 18428 (child process of PID 11272) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 11272 (child process of PID 16416) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 16416 (child process of PID 788) has been terminated.
```

Both my PySpark and Spark are the same versions.

Comment: can you show the entire traecback

Comment: @Jeril Here it is. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: @Jeril findspark did not work but the second one, the PYTHONPATH did. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try any of the following solutions:

**Solution 1**

*Install findspark*

```
pip install findspark
```

*In you code use:*

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

Optionally you can also specify `"/path/to/spark"` in the init method above:

```
findspark.init("/path/to/spark")
```

**Solution 2:**

As outlined @ [pyspark error does not exist in the jvm error when initializing SparkContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161939/pyspark-error-does-not-exist-in-the-jvm-error-when-initializing-sparkcontext), adding `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (with value as:

`%SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-<version>-src.zip:%PYTHONPATH%`,

- just check what `py4j` version you have in your `spark/python/lib` folder) helped resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`no attribute 'getorCreate'. Did you mean: 'getOrCreate'?`

Try capitalising the "o".

Comment: I did do that but it still give me the same error.